ontap on notificaiton didnt initiate onMessageOpenedApp Firebase Flutter
hi i used this $payload = [
        'message' => [
            'token' => $token,
            // 'notification' => [
              //'title' => 'hey chat'
            // ],
            'data' => [
                'title' => $notification['title'],
                 'description' => $notification['body']['description'],
                'click_action' => 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK',
                'body' => json_encode($notification['body']),
            ],
            'android' => [
                'priority' => 'high',
            ],
        ],
    ];

this is my api side code if i comment it
  // 'notification' => [
              //'title' => 'hey chat'
            // ],

i have to comment it becuase i want to show a custom sound when get chat request so now removing it problem is notification tap is not working when app is in recentList background i dont need notificaiton i alrady have create a customsound notification
Future<void> foregroundNotificatioCustomAuddio(RemoteMessage payload) async {
      final initializationSettingsDarwin = DarwinInitializationSettings(
        defaultPresentBadge: true,
        requestSoundPermission: true,
        requestBadgePermission: true,
        defaultPresentSound: false,
        onDidReceiveLocalNotification: (id, title, body, payload) async {
          return;
        },
      );

      log('payload is ${payload.data['title']}');
      log('payload description 1 ${payload.data['description']}');

      final android = const AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher');
      final initialSetting = InitializationSettings(
          android: android, iOS: initializationSettingsDarwin);

      localNotifications.initialize(initialSetting,
          onDidReceiveNotificationResponse: (NotificationResponse response) {
        print('Notification tapped: ${response.payload}');
        if (response.payload != null) {
          onSelectNotification(response.payload!); // Navigate or handle payload
        }
      });
      final customSound = 'app_sound.wav';
      AndroidNotificationDetails androidDetails = const AndroidNotificationDetails(
        'channel_id_17',
        'channel.name',
        importance: Importance.max,
        icon: "@mipmap/ic_launcher",
        playSound: true,
        enableVibration: true,
        sound: RawResourceAndroidNotificationSound('app_sound'),
      );

      final iOSDetails = DarwinNotificationDetails(
        sound: customSound,
      );
      final platformChannelSpecifics =
          NotificationDetails(android: androidDetails, iOS: iOSDetails);
      global.sp = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

      if (global.sp!.getString("currentUser") != null) {
        await localNotifications.show(
          10,
          payload.data['title'], //message.data["title"]
          payload.data['description'] ?? '',
          platformChannelSpecifics,
          payload: json.encode(payload.data.toString()),
        );
      }

}

This question is similar to: Flutter - FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen is not triggered. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
